# Why does CLion's implement methods shortcut make the method private?

Tags: c++, clion

I have the following base class:

```
class OpCode {
public:
    OpCode(const std::shared_ptr<CharacterContext> &characterContext);

    virtual void operator()(std::uint_fast32_t argument) = 0;
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<CharacterContext> character_context;
};
```

If I declare a class like this:

```
class xxx : OpCode {
public:
   using OpCode::OpCode;
}
```

and then do ^I to implement methods and select `operator()` it creates:

```
private:
    void operator()(std::uint_fast32_t argument) override {

    }
```

Why is it making this `private`? Shouldn't it be `public`? I'm wondering if there's some underlying C++ idiom that I don't know.

Comment: You use `private` inheritance so it makes sense.

Comment: @user7860670 What's `private` inheritance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: @user7860670 but I'm not specifying a modifier on the base class. The default is `private`? I'd think the default would be `public`.

Comment: yes, default is `private`, just like for class members

Comment: default is `private` with `class` and `public` with `struct`